# 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer after running a created function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a code that should plot multiple scatter charts at once.

```
def plot_scatter_figures(chart_title,data, number_plots, selected_x, selected_y,chart_titles, color,x_labels,y_labels,color_labels,cmap):
    """Plot Scatter figures
    
    Args:
        chart_title (string): Chart Title
        data (np.array): numpy array of data
        number_plots (tuple): The number of plots in i*j format
        selected_x (list): A list of desired x-axes ;i.e columns of array
        selected_y (list): A list of desired y-axes ;i.e columns of array
        chart_titles (list): A list of charts titles
        color (list): A list of desired color based variable; i.e. column of array
        x_labels (list): A list of x-axis labels
        y_labels (list): A list of y-axis labels
        color_labels (list): A list of color labels
        cmap (list): A list of color palette 
    
    Returns:
        plt: plot the data
    """
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(number_plots,figsize=(30,15),dpi = 80)
    fig.suptitle(chart_title,fontsize = 20)
    
    for i,j in (number_plots):
        for k in len(selected_x):
            axs[i,j].scatter(data[selected_x[k]],data[selected_y[k]],c=data[color[k]], marker=".", s=80, cmap=cmap[k])
            plt.colorbar((axs[i,j].scatter(data[selected_x[k]],data[selected_y[k]],c=data[color[k]], marker=".", s=80, cmap=cmap[k])),ax=axs[i,j]).ax.set_title(color[k],fontsize = 10)
            axs[i,j].set_title(chart_titles[i], fontsize =15)
            axs[i,j].set_xlabel(x_label[k], fontsize = 15)
            axs[i,j].set_ylabel(y_label[k], fontsize = 15)
```

However, after creating the required input I'm getting the following error:

---

```
------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-99-0230861df084> in <module>()
----> 1 plot_scatter_figures(chart_title,grandstand_fm2, number_plots, selected_x, selected_y,chart_titles, color,x_labels,y_labels,color_label,cmap)

2 frames

<ipython-input-98-10e25b3df9fe> in plot_scatter_figures(chart_title, data, number_plots, selected_x, selected_y, chart_titles, color, x_labels, y_labels, color_labels, cmap)
     18         plt: plot the data
     19     """
---> 20     fig, axs = plt.subplots(number_plots,figsize=(30,15),dpi = 80)
     21     fig.suptitle(chart_title,fontsize = 20)
     22 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex, sharey, squeeze, subplot_kw, gridspec_kw, **fig_kw)
   1178     axs = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey,
   1179                        squeeze=squeeze, subplot_kw=subplot_kw,
-> 1180                        gridspec_kw=gridspec_kw)
   1181     return fig, axs
   1182 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in subplots(self, nrows, ncols, sharex, sharey, squeeze, subplot_kw, gridspec_kw)
   1567 
   1568         # Create array to hold all axes.
-> 1569         axarr = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype=object)
   1570         for row in range(nrows):
   1571             for col in range(ncols):

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I'd appreciate any input to fix this issue.

Comment: The first two arguments to `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()` are the number of rows and columns. I don't see a `figsize` option.

Comment: What's your `number_plots`?

Comment: @QuangHoang a tuple contains the number of rows and number of columns so `number_plots = (2,3)` will have 2 rows and 3 columns of charts.

Comment: @Barmar figsize is fixed at 30,15

Comment: Read the documentation of the function. It has no `figsize` named argument. The first 2 arguments are positional, and they should both be a single number.

Comment: @Barmar yes, `figsize` is accepted, the document has `**kwargs`.

Comment: @AliJ the signature is `subplots(num_rows, num_cols)`. You need to unpack that `num_plots`. But then `for i,j in (num_plots)` will fail.

Comment: @Barmar I got it now. However the function is still not operating the way I desire.

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you so much for the input. I unpacked into two extra variables. and changed the for loop into `for i, j in zip(range(n_rows), range(n_cols)):` However the charts are looking stupid. It's only plotting 2, instead of 6 and stacking all the colorbars into one chart. I'm not sure if I should open a new topic since your response answers the original question.

Comment: unpack wih a star `plt.subplots(*number_plots...`

Comment: If any one is still interested, the fix is to call `axs.ravel()` and iterate with `for i in len(selected_x)`